# Simple self-hosted sync system for Android contacts and calendar events

Tags: android, backup, calendar, synchronization, contact-manager

I want to be able to backup and share Android contacts and calendar events without using Google.

As such, I am seeking software recommendations for a ***simple*** self-hosted sync system for Android contacts and calendar events.

***Requirements for the Server***

- Runs on Android KitKat or Windows 7
- Simple to install: Does *not* require installing many bulky packages.
- Simple to enable/disable the server.  It will only be manually run when needed (approx 10 minutes/week), and no component of it should be running all the time.
- Completely self-hosted

***Requirements for the Clients***

- Android KitKat compatible
- Can require a separate app to perform the sync or can integrate itself into the OS (either way is fine).
- Supports multiple clients, but does not need to support simultaneous sync operations.

***General Requirements***

- No recurring fees (prefer [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), but one-time fee acceptable)
- Must be able to handle contacts with multiple custom fields
- Must be able to handle recurring calendar events
- Must be reliable

**Notes**:

- **ownCloud** looks excellent, but it seems to require running several bulky layers below its code for Windows, and does not appear to have a server version to run on Android.
- **Baikal** looks very good as well, but I have not found much documentation regarding installation details. According to the docs that I did find, Baikal requires an Apache2 webserver complete with PHP 5.3.1 with PDO and SQLite3 or MySQL extensions and a DOM (php-xml) extension. That seems like a lot to install, configure, and maintain.
- I'm looking at **Radicale**. It requires Python, which does not run all the time. I'm looking at the code to see how Radicale is acting as a server without a separate webserver layer. Or perhaps it is an on-demand system, which would be perfect.

Comment: That's why I didn't make it an answer: neither I use it myself, nor have I even investigated deep enough. So, Baïkal itself is lightweight (they say so), but requires "heavy components" under the hood. Ouch. So I'm afraid [Sabredav](https://code.google.com/p/sabredav/) is no option either (requires PHP + MySQL). Maybe [Radicale](http://radicale.org/)? Sounds very promising: "light solution, easy to use, easy to install, easy to configure … requires few software dependencies". FOSS. X-platform. Works out-of-the-box. 47kB download. But seems to need Python.

Comment: As you're doing the main research (I just cued the idea), I'd suggest you make it an answer then – even if it somehow turns out to not be a "perfect match". Radicale should come pretty close :)